# Input on same line as output in C#

Tags: c#, console, user-input

For example:

**C:\> Input a number: 60**

Where the output would be "Input a number: " and the input would be "60".

How do I get these to be on the same line?

The problem is when I output "Input a number: ", it automatically starts a new line, so the user inputs "60" underneath (on the next line).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `System.Console.Write` instead of `System.Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 9):

It would be

```
Console.Write("Input a number: ");

// It will return the entire string after the user hits enter
string theNumber = Console.ReadLine();

int number = 0;

if(int.TryParse(theNumber, out number))
{
  // Do something with the number
}
```